# In aem/cq5 allow user to access secure(denied access for anonymous user) page without logging in

Tags: aem

We have requirement that user should be able to access secure page (which is denied access for anonymous user only allowed for logged in user).
User will be getting email link with path,once user clicks on that link 
user should be allowed to access that secure page only.If user tries to click non any other secure page ,user should be shown login screen.
ex: http://wwww.test.com/home.html?path=/secure/page1.html
now when user clicks on link ,user should be able see page1.html

Comment: Are you using the OOTB  authentication servlet and ACLs for your users' account or do you have a site integrated with a different authentication & authorisation solution?

Comment: we are using custom authentication handler